# Acomodar datos JSON con PHP

Tags: php, json

Tengo algunos inconvenientes para acomodar datos obtenidos de una API, los mismos vienen en formato "JSON", intente acomodar los mismos mediante un "array" pero no tuve exito.

Los datos que me arroja el API al momento de realizar un "Get" son los siguientes:

```
{

    "page_count": "integer",
    "page_number": "integer",
    "page_size": "integer",
    "total_records": "integer",
    "accounts": [
        {
            "id": "string [uuid]",
            "account_name": "string",
            "email": "string",
            "account_type": "string",
            "subscription_start_time": "string [date-time]",
            "subscription_end_time": "string [date-time]",
            "created_at": "string [date-time]"
        }
    ]
}
```

En base al Código anterior, me gustaria obtener el "ID, Account_Name, Email, Account_Type" unicamente, de cada cuenta.

Alguien podria brindarme algun ejemplo?

Gracias, saludos!

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: mira esto: http://jsfiddle.net/cyzbktsp/4/

Answer (score 2):

Hola buenos dias a todos,

Les comento que ya encontre como acomodar la informacion que arroja el API en formato JSON, de igual forma lo anexo abajo, espero le sirva a alguien mas.

```
$response = curl_exec($ch); // En la variable response se encuentra guardado el URL del API "Get"
$response = json_decode($response, true);

foreach($response['accounts'] as $item) {
print '<strong>ID:</strong> ' . $item['id'];
print ' - ';
print '<strong>Nombre de la cuenta:</strong> ' . $item['account_name'];
print ' - ';
print '<strong>Email:</strong> ' . $item['email'];
print ' - ';
print '<strong>Tipo de cuenta:</strong> ' . $item['account_type'];
print '<br>';
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: si exactamente así debias hacerlo, debes mejorar tu manera de hacer las preguntas, pero me alegro que  hayas encontrado una respuesta, saludos.